# How to mock method with parameters

Tags: moq

I am still learning Moq and am writing a unit test using Moq:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessFileRowQueue()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<EdiEntityManager>();
        mock.Setup(s => s.GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess()).Returns(GetMockFileRowEntities);
        var controller = new EdiController("LOCAL", mock.Object);
                    controller.ProcessFileRowQueue();
    }
```

This works.

Now, I want to ensure that the ensure ProcessFileRowQueue() actually did it's job.  There is a method on EdiManager that I would like to mock so I can intercept the parameters and inspect them and ensure they are correct.

```
public virtual void SaveNewEdiDocument(EdiDocument ediDocument, Translation translation)...
```

However, I don't see how to mock a method with parameters.

This is what I thought it would be:

```
mock.Setup(s => s.SaveNewEdiDocument(It.IsAny<EdiDocument>(), It.IsAny<Translation>()).Returns(ValidateResults));
```

How do I write this, or is there a different way I should be verifying the results?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Callback method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessFileRowQueue()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<EdiEntityManager>();
        mock.Setup(s => s.GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess()).Returns(GetMockFileRowEntities);
        mock.Setup(s => s.SaveNewEdiDocument(It.IsAny<EdiDocument>(), It.IsAny<Translation>()))
            .Callback<EdiDocument, Translation>(VerifyResult);
        var controller = new EdiController("LOCAL", mock.Object);

        controller.ProcessFileRowQueue();
    }

    public void VerifyResult(EdiDocument ediDocument, Translation translation)
    {

    }
```